# apple mach o linker error creating basic AI CC Plugin

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, adobe-illustrator

there are quite a no. of question on this point. But none of them can guide a solution to my issue. I am trying to [create a plugin for Adobe Illustrator CC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator.html) in *XCode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)*. Following their official guidelines to create a basic "HelloWorld" plugin giving this linker error.
Error:

```
Ld /Users/Barun/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015\ SDK/samplecode/output/mac/debug/HelloWorld.bundle/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld normal x86_64
cd "/Users/Barun/Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 SDK/samplecode/HelloWorld"
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/Barun/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015\ SDK/samplecode/output/mac/debug -F/Users/Barun/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015\ SDK/samplecode/output/mac/debug -filelist /Users/Barun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fzhjlvdzxxobzagznysauclanlgg/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HelloWorld.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -dead_strip -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Barun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fzhjlvdzxxobzagznysauclanlgg/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HelloWorld_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Barun/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015\ SDK/samplecode/output/mac/debug/HelloWorld.bundle/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFStringCreateWithCharacters", referenced from:
ai::UnicodeString::as_CFString(__CFAllocator const*) const in IAIUnicodeString.o
"_CFStringGetCharactersPtr", referenced from:
ai::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(__CFString const* const&) in IAIUnicodeString.o
"_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
ai::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(__CFString const* const&) in IAIUnicodeString.o
"_CFStringGetCharacters", referenced from:
ai::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(__CFString const* const&) in IAIUnicodeString.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looks like the linking error coming from IAIUnicodeString.cpp file, which is a support file provided by the sdk. So I am not having idea to what need to be change there.

I was successful to build **FreeGrid** and **DrawArt** project provided with the SDK as sample. I have also checked all the build settings with **FreeGrid** to my **HelloWorld** project, no mismatch from that side too.

The project set up can be found in [Github](https://github.com/barunhalderkolkata/HelloWorld).

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe Forum https://forums.adobe.com/message/7723859#7723859:

Add to project settings:

BuildPhases>Link Binary With Libraries: CoreFoundation.framework